# How to apply className that is passed to component in nextjs

Tags: html, css, next.js

I next.js,from parent to child component the className is passed as props.
Here cardClassName and bgColor are className props.

```
function Use_Cases({ caseData, cardClassName, bgcolor }) {
  return (
    <section className={use_case.use_case_section + ' '}>
      <div
        className={clsx(
          'cx-container',
          use_case.use_case_content,
          use_case[{ cardClassName }]
        )}
      >
        <p className={clsx(use_case.section_header_text)}>Use Cases</p>
        <div className={clsx(use_case.card_section)}>
         .
         .

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

EDIT

```
 <UseCase
          caseData={use_case}
          cardClassName='cdn-use-case'
          bgcolor='blue-background'
  />
```

Tried every way but in vain.
Is there any solution for it to work

Comment: Why do you add `bgcolor` as  a string? And what does `clsx` do?

Comment: clsx function can take any number of arguments.. https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly is wrong with the code? Is your `<div>` element that is attempting to join three different class names not rendering the expected output? If so, assuming `use_case` is an object literal, you're passing in another object literal into the brackets when you do `use_case[{ cardClassName }]`. This translates to `use_case['[object Object]']`. If `cardClassName` is a property in `use_case`, you can access it by doing `use_case[cardClassName]`.

Comment: Yeah, please add the definition of `use_case` and where it is imported or comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this with an example:

In `/index.tsx`

```
import NewComp from '../Components/NewComp'

export default function index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NewComp classes='class-1 my class-2' />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here, `class-1 my class-2` are the class names that are passed to child `NewComp`

In `../Components/NewComp`

```
import $ from '../Styles/card.module.css'

export default function NewComp({ classes }: { classes: string }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`${$.card} ${classes}`}>
        NewComp component which will render nothing.
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Accept the classes props from parent as `({classes})` and use template literals to pass this to the desired location. Here, to a div element.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like in browser---

> [image]
> You can see, we've all the components passed as props, with those coming from style sheets (here `$`)